# How to make RTCPeerConnection be available in Kotlin/JS without declaring the class myself?

Tags: javascript, typescript, kotlin, webrtc, kotlin-js

I am trying out Kotlin/JS.

As an exercice to learn something new I wanted to mess with WebRTC. I've been following the basic examples on their site and at some point you have to instantiate an object from the `RTCPeerConnection` class. Something very straight forward and available without installing any dependencies.

If I come on the browser's console I can easily do:

[image: Browser screenshot]

However in my IntelliJ the compiler screams at me stating that there is no such class so I can't instantiate it.

Now I know of two ways I *could* get around to this:

1. Using `fun js(code: String): dynamic`, which works but I lose all intelli-sense and type-safety making me really sad (and kind of missing the point of using Kotlin)
2. Declaring (using `external` keyword) the entirety of the RTC spec which is *very extense* and that also makes me really sad

I've found out a way to hack my way around the second approach but still is not good enough:

I've installed `@types/webrtc` from NPM in this fashion:

```
implementation(npm("@types/webrtc", "0.0.30", generateExternals=true))
```

So I could trick Dukat to generate the external declarations for me and I've actually succeeded!

*… or that's what I thought*

[image: Error]

[Yeah, seems like they've declared the RTCPeerConnection as an interface and not as a class so I am out of luck](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/webrtc/RTCPeerConnection.d.ts)

Has somebody worked this out of it?

Comment: can you use the `js()` blob and then cast to the generated dukat type ?

Comment: That's a smart approach, I'll give it a shot

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Because when attempting to compile the Kotlin/JS project seems like Dukat generates repeated properties and it does not compile

Comment: As workaround you can generate declarations from "@types/webrtc" into kt files using standalone version of dukat or through gradle integration with `generateExternals` task, for more information check out https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-external-declarations-with-dukat.html

Comment: This was suggested on reddit. It did not work because the types generated by Dukat had duplicated properties and the code wouldn't compile at all!

Comment: in that case you sadly have to disable dukat for that dependency and write the external declarations yourself.. ideally using the not quite working dukat stuff as a base